# how to add multiple data in chart js dynamically from JSON

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this below JSON. I want to display the below data in chart js. for each label "2020Q2" i will be having group of bars. Currently i have added this as static. How to add to dataset  as dynamic.

JSON which need to be displayed as bars for each Quarter-

```
 {
        "2020Q2": {
            "defendtarget": 0,
            "target": 0,
            "totaldisplacement": 2
        },
        "2020Q3": {
            "defendtarget": 0,
            "target": 0,
            "totaldisplacement": 2
        }
    }
```

JS -

```
_buildDouChart() {
    var labelset = [];
    var dataset = [];
    for ( let key in this.aggResult )
    {
        if ( this.aggResult.hasOwnProperty( key ) )
        {
            this.labelset.push( key );
            this.dataset.push( this.aggResult[ key ] );
        }
    }
    let canvas = this.template.querySelector( "canvas.chart" );
    let context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
    this.chart = new window.Chart( context, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: this.labelset,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'defendtarget',
                    backgroundColor: "#fd3612",
                    data: [ 1, 1 ],
                },
                {
                    label: 'target',
                    backgroundColor: "#f9d342",
                    data: [ 1, 1 ]
                },
                {
                    label: 'totaldisplacement',
                    backgroundColor: "#f9d342",
                    data: [ 2, 2 ]
                },
            ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [ {
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    },
                }, ]
            }
        }
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for passing the data dynamically as you get from the data source, you need to maintain three arrays each for each bar.

that is one for **defendTarget**, **target** and **totalDisplacement**..

As you get the object from the data source,
You need to segregate the number of object. For that you can use the following line:

```
this.totalRecords=Object.keys(this.data)
```

Then suppose you need to generate the array for **defendTarget**. You need to use the following logic:

```
this.totalRecords.forEach((record)=>{
    this.defendTargetData.push(record.defendTarget)
     })
```

edit:
For getting the number of bars you want you need to use the following code:

```
this.totalBars = Object.keys(this.totalRecords[0])
```

And now you can update the code for dataset as:

```
 this.totalBars.forEach((bar)={
  currentDataSet = {label:bar,backgroundColor: 
     "#fd3612",data:[]};
  this.totalRecords.forEach((record)=>{
        currentDataSet.data.push(record.bar)
       })
   this.dataSet.push(currentDataSet)
  })
```

I hope this would fit into your requirement.

Comment: Hi Minal, Is it possible to create the entire dataset dynmically rather creating only data.. meaning creating label and background color..rather hardcoding...as there might be a chance where a addtional bar need to be created with different data.

Comment: Hey, even that is possible, I have updated the answer according to your requirement, please have a look.